# Combining Spacy PoS and NER

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm using Spacy for NLP and can't solve a Problem by myself.

This is my function, it recieves a list of lists with tokens:

```
def lemmatization(texts, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB']):
    """https://spacy.io/api/annotation"""
    texts_out = []
    for sent in tqdm(texts):
        mytokens = nlp(" ".join(sent))
        # mytokens = [ent.label_.lower() if ent.label_ == "DATE" or ent.label_ == "TIME" for ent in mytokens]
        mytokens = [word.lemma_ if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens if word.pos_ in allowed_postags]
        mytokens = [word for word in mytokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations]
        mytokens = " ".join([i for i in mytokens])
        texts_out.append(mytokens)
    return texts_out
```

The out-commented line should point to something I want to add.
The idea was to check if a token belongs to the entity "DATE" or "TIME". If yes the entity should be returned as lower case if no either the lemma or lower case of the word should be returned. (See line below)
Unfortunately, I cannot manage to implement this successfully. Could someone please help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Could you post just one value for `texts`?

Comment: texts = [['test', 'monday'], ['test', 'april']]